# Quotient of a dedekind domain in a numberfield by a primeideal is a perfect field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I have the following question. Is the quotient of a dedekind domain A in a numberfield K by a prime I always a perfect field? I understand it for the ring of integers in a finite (separable) extension K of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite rank. Maybe someone can help me. :)

EDIT: First of all i see that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq A$ and that $I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a (nonzero) primeideal (p). So I see $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq A/I$. does it help?

Comment: You also know that $A$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module. In particular, the quotient is a finite extension of $\mathbb F_p$.